# How to select an Array with a specific title at first in UIPicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multidimensional-array, uipickerview

Hello i want to show a list in a UIPicker, which is saved in arrays.

It works but i want to select a specific title as standard. it should be automatic selected.

example:

> Array
>
> index_***_*___**_title
>
> 0_***_*__*_*___**_Water
>
> 1_***_*__*_*___**_Fire  <--- the title with the name Fire should be
>   automatically selected as standart.
>
> 2_***_*__*_*___**_Storm

My list is flexible and i cannot select everytime the index 1. 
Do you have any ideas for this problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: By index 1 did you mean that the picker should always select the middle row?

Comment: no it should always select the row with the title fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieve this you need to use  [selectRow:inComponent:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

```
self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 155, 0, 0)];
self.pickerView.delegate = self;
self.pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.pickerView selectRow:[YouArray indexOfObject:@"YourTitle"] inComponent:0 animated:NO];

[self.view addSubview:self.pickerView];
```

Comment: i dont know the index of the array just the title. i need to select the row where title = fire

Comment: thank you for the solution ill check it out tomorrow and tell you if it works

Comment: @ErayGeveci-okay..i m waiting for ur replay :) all d best :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the documentation will give you the answer. Do it like this: Remember you have to do it somewhere on or after the `viewDidLoad` on your ViewController life cycle.

```
[myPickerView selectRow:indexYouWantSelected inComponent:columnInCaseYouHaveMany animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the index of Fire

```
    NSArray *array = @[@"Water",@"Fire",@"Storm"];

    NSString *stringToBeSelected = @"Fire";

    NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *currentString = (NSString *)obj;
        return [currentString isEqualToString:stringToBeSelected];

    }];
```

Select the row of pickerView

```
[self.pickerView selectRow:index inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```